# Alerts on List based on Items shown in View not working

Tags: 2010, list, alert, view

I got a custom list with fairly standard columns:
- Single line of text
- Multiple lines of text
- Choice
- Number
- Yes/No

I set up a default alert on it, add an item, and just as expected, I get an email alert about the new item. Simple enough.

I then create a new view with the following filter:
- Show items only when the following is true:

> Show the items when column
>   [YesNoColumn]
>   is equal to
>   Yes

I then create an alert with the following settings:
- Only send alerts when: *All changes*
- Send me an alert when: *Someone changes an item that appears in the following view: [myNewView]*

The issue now is when I create or edit an item that appears in the new view (items with `[YesNoColumn] == Yes`), I do not get an alert at all.

I've looked around and found that [alerts won't work views with filter on system-generated/calculated columns](http://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2010/03/11/no-able-to-set-alerts-for-some-views-in-sharepoint-list/). I'm not sure if this is related though as I do not have a calculated field on my list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did some testing and it seems that filters on some column types doesn't cause alerts to go off.

Examples of column types that work on alerts on views with filters:

> Single line
>   Multiple line
>   Choice

Examples of column types that do NOT work on alerts on views with filters:

> Yes/No (The one I was using)
>   Calculated Field

In the end, I managed to fix my issue by changing the *[YesNoColumn]* into a Choice one.