# SharePoint 2010 - alert on library view

Tags: custom, alert, view, document-set

I have SharePoint 2010 site and I want to set an alert on custom library custom view (library is filled with document-sets).
As I searched for this problem, in this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/alerts-on-custom-views) are mentioned few requirements (which I think, are fulfilled):

> 1) "It must have a where clause" - my desired view have sorting and filtering.
>
> 2) "It must be a public view" - so it is!
>
> 3) "It cannot involve content approval" - done!

But in the end, I do not have possibility to create alert for view. When creating alert, in section "Send alerts for these changes" I do not have an option "Someone changes an item that appears in the following view:" and do not have a dropdown with possible views to choose from.

What could be the problem and how to set an alert for custom library  custom view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view has to contain a filter and only some types of columns will work for the view-based alerts. Check this answer for column types: [Alerts on List based on Items shown in View not working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117102/alerts-on-list-based-on-items-shown-in-view-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a workflow that runs on create/change and uses IF statements that match your view filters?

Comment: I have, but alerts suits better for my situation - workflow will be my plan-B, if this problem will not be resolved. Besides - I want to know, why this problem exist and how to solve it!

Comment: Please refer to this other post: 
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/alerts-on-custom-views

Comment: In main text I already have a link to this post. Tried everything that was mentioned in comment, but it did not worked.